# Javascript - How to define Arrays inside an Object using Loops?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, canvas

I'm trying to make a Pixel RPG game, and am a bit confused.

What I'm trying to do:

```
var character = {
    gender: male,
    age: 18,
    action: walking,
    direction: left,
    skin: 0,
    eyes: aqua,
    hairStyle: 0,
    hairColor: blue,
    hat: 'cap'
};

ctx.drawImage(characterIMG.body[character.gender][character.skinColor], 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(characterIMG.eyes[character.gender][character, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(characterIMG.hair[style0], 0, 0); 
if(character.hat != "none"){
    ctx.drawImage(characterIMG.hat['cap'], 0, 0);
}
```

How would I go about defining the images?

So far got here, but am mixed up..

```
var characterIMG = [male, female]; //I want some separate variables to just write in, in case I need to add more images of the same type, then I can just write the "type" in the variable instead of changing a bunch of stuff :)

for(var i in characterIMG){
    characterIMG[i] = {
        skin: [],
        eyes: [],
        hair: [],
        accessories: []
    }
}
```

Unless there is a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

--In short, I want to do this:

```
ctx.drawImage(characterIMG.body[character.gender][character.skinColor], 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(characterIMG.eyes[character.gender][character], 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(characterIMG.hair[style0], 0, 0);
```

..with `characterIMG` containing a huge database of all the relevant images (this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a set of images as follows

```
// a list of image name comma delimited
const imageURLs = "image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg";

// create an array of images
const myImageList = imageURLs.split(",").map(url => {
    const image = new Image;
    image.src = url;
    return image;
});
```

If you have many images with different categories and subcategories then it will depend on how you organise the images on your file system. If you have one directory and all the images in that then each image's name should have some description of the image

```
 body_dark_female.jpg
 body_light_female.jpg
 body_dark_male.jpg
 body_light_male.jpg
 head_dark_female.jpg
 head_light_female.jpg
 head_dark_male.jpg
 head_light_male.jpg
```

And so on, or a better option is to set the various categories in directories

```
 body/dark/female/jill.jpg
 body/dark/male/tom.jpg
 body/light/female/jill.jpg
 body/light/male/tom.jpg
 head/light/female/jill.jpg
 head/light/male/tom.jpg
 head/dark/female/jill.jpg
 head/dark/male/tom.jpg
```

You can then use the name or directories to create the data structure

```
 // using the directory structure
 function loadImage(imageURL,images){
     const cats = imageURL.split("/");  // split the cats into an array
     // remove the last item as that is the image name
     var name = cats.pop();
     // remove the extension and add just the image name to the cats
     cats.push(name.split(".")[0]);
     // reference the base category
     var currentCat = images; 
     cats.forEach(cat => {  // for each category create the objects
          if(currentCat[cat] === undefined){ // does this cat exist?
              currentCat[cat] = {}; // no them create an object for it
          }
          currentCat = currentCat[cat]; // reference the category 
     });
     // now create the image and add it to the object
     currentCat = new Image;
     currentCat.src = imageURL;
 }
```

Then use the directory listing to create the list of images to load

```
 const imageURLs = `
     body/dark/female/jill.jpg
     body/dark/male/tom.jpg
     body/light/female/jill.jpg
     body/light/male/tom.jpg
     head/light/female/jill.jpg
     head/light/male/tom.jpg
     head/dark/female/jill.jpg
     head/dark/male/tom.jpg
 `;
```

Because the directory listing may be a bit unclean (spaces, tabs, linefeeds, etc) you should ensure each image name is valid

```
  // remove tabs, groups of spaces and returns, and use linefeed to seperate them
  const imagesURLClean = imageURLs.replace(/\t|\r| +?/g,"").split("\n");

  // create the base category
  const characterIMG = {};

  // add the images
  imagesURLClean.forEach(imageURL => loadImage(imageURL,characterIMG));
```

When that has run you can access the image as follows

```
 ctx.drawImage(characterIMG.body.light.female.jill,0,0);
```

Or via strings

```
 var part = "body";
 var skin = "light";
 var gender = "female";
 var name = "jill";

 ctx.drawImage(characterIMG[part][skin][gender][name],0,0);
```

The directory listing will create the following data structure

```
 characterIMG = {
     body : {
        dark : {
           female : {
              jill : // the image
           },
           male : {
              tom : // the image
           },
        },
        light : {
           female : {
              jill : // the image
           },
           male : {
              tom : // the image
           },
        }
     },
     head : {
        dark : {
           female : {
              jill : // the image
           },
           male : {
              tom : // the image
           },
        },
        light : {
           female : {
              jill : // the image
           },
           male : {
              tom : // the image
           },
        }
     }
```

If your list is very long it may have missing items, during development it would pay to add a default category that will return an image appropriate for that category.

Thus you directory listing would look like

```
     body/default.jpg           // default
     body/light/default.jpg     // default
     body/light/female/default.jpg    // default
     body/light/male/default.jpg      // default
     body/dark/default.jpg            // default
     body/dark/female/default.jpg     // default
     body/dark/female/jill.jpg
     body/dark/male/default.jpg       // default
     body/dark/male/tom.jpg

     // and so on
```

Then create a function that gets a image via category and if it has problems it will use the default image as far as it can find to fit the categories

```
  function getImage(images, ...categories){
     const count = 0;         
     var image = images
     while(count < categories.length){
         if(image[categories[count]] !== undefined){
             image = image[categories[count++]];
         }else{
             return image.default;
         }
     }
     return image;
  }
```

Then you can draw an image as follows

```
  ctx.drawImage(getImage(characterIMG,"body","dark","female","jill"),0,0);

  // when you get the wrong referance            
  ctx.drawImage(getImage(characterIMG,"leg","dark","female","jill"),0,0);
  // it will return characterIMG.default
  // or
  ctx.drawImage(getImage(characterIMG,"body","dark","female","bill"),0,0);
  // as there is no female bill, it will return characterIMG.body.dark.female.default
```

Comment: I kinda figured this out already xD haha cool how you said the same thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use an object and then just new up the object whenever you want to create a new instance of a character. With this, each character can inherit their properties from the main Object (via prototype) and become a separate entity within your game.

```js
var Person = function(payload) {
  this.name   = payload.name;
  this.age    = payload.age;
  this.gender = payload.gender;
};

Person.prototype.talk = function() {
  return console.log('hello, I am ' + this.name); 
}

var Person1 = new Person({
  name    : 'Amanda',
  age     : 18,
  gender  : 'Female',
});

var Person2 = new Person({
  name    : 'Sam',
  age     : 21,
  gender  : 'Make',
});

Person1.talk();
Person2.talk();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I already have that, I'm trying to keep a single huge object/array for all my `IMAGES` instead of defining separate arrays for each section of the image.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you define an array inside an object.

```js
var characterIMG = {
  male: {
      skins: [],
      hair: ["black", "brown"]  
  },
  female: {
      skins: [],
      hair: []
  }
};
console.log(characterIMG);

console.log(characterIMG["male"]["hair"]);
console.log(characterIMG.male.hair); //does the same
```

Comment: I'm trying to define IMAGES using LOOPS inside the object. Sorry if I sound confusing

Comment: @tery.blargh replace the string "black" by the image and you're done :)

Comment: Thank you for the effort in your answer. There are 100s of Images :'( I need to use a loop!